# Caught Google service Exception 401 message is Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "unauthorized_client" }

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am using google api php client.I got this error while upload file to youtube. I got token and put in a txt file. Its fresh token and its not supposed to expire. Why am i keep getting this error. My client and secret id is ok and never changed after genereting token. Searched over google for few days but no luck. Here is the tutorial link i am following https://www.domsammut.com/code/php-server-side-youtube-v3-oauth-api-video-upload-guide Thank you.